# OpenCV in Qpython

Tags: android, python, opencv, qpython

I'm developing a project (in Python)  that does video processing using OpenCV. Now I'm planning to implement that in my android phone. I read that Qpython supports python on android. **So is there any way to import third party libs like OpenCV in Qpython.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can go though my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38598880/how-do-i-install-modules-on-qpython3-android-port-of-python/49348725#49348725

Answer (score 1):

You can install opencv from qpython libraries(install from QPypi).

QPython --> Libraries --> QPypi --> opencv-qpython --> install

Use it as
import cv

Answer (score 0):

In Qpython3 there is a pip program (not sure if on qpython too) but running that program you can "pip install [your module]" Worked for me installing sqlalchemy and youtube_dl